# Creating triangular bootstrap badges

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create triangular bootstrap badge with text at center of the triangle.
Code for normal badge: https://jsfiddle.net/wqrry89r/
Code for triangular bootstrap badge: https://jsfiddle.net/wqrry89r/1/
My CSS code is:

```
.badge-triangle {
  left: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #777;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.badge-triangle:after {
  left: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #FFF;
  left: 57px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  content: '';
}
```

How can I make that bootstrap badge triangular and make text go to center of triangle?

Comment: First thought is **don't do it with borders**.

Comment: You also need to clarify whether these badges have dynamic text and whether or not they will be fixed sizes. At the moment this is too broad.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Text is dynamic... And texts can be either short or long

Comment: Then you can't do this with CSS. You need javascript to ascertain the elements dimensions.

Comment: Okay, I'll try in javascript. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.badge {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
 border-top: 90px solid #CC0000;
 border-left: 90px solid transparent;
}
.mask-t {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;

}
.mask-t strong {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, -25%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, -25%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, -25%);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, -25%);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, -25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="badge">
</div>
<div class="mask-t">
  <strong>Sale!</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Works okay... however this isn't a bootstrap badge

Answer (score 0):

Although right answer has already been provided but just want to give another thought.
This is using normal CSS (not bootstrap badge) but modifying actual code only.
Here, I have considered "my-triangle" as main triangle.

HTML changes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container my-triangle">
    <span class="badge-triangle"></span>
    <span class="new-text">N.T.A</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS changes:

```
.my-triangle{
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  left:100px
}

.badge-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position:absolute;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #777;
}

.badge-triangle:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
  left: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  content: '';
}

.new-text{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:100px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Please check this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/wqrry89r/3/